# RefreshTokenAsync() hangs in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, auth0

I have successfully implemented auth0 login in a xamarin app, however Im having issues with refreshing the token when needed.

```
public async Task<bool> CheckToken()
{
    try
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------(AuthService) Attempting token refresh");
        var refreshedToken = await _auth0Client.RefreshTokenAsync(storedToken);
        System.Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------(AuthService) Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        await SecureStorage.SetAsync("***-IdToken", refreshedToken.IdentityToken);
        await SecureStorage.SetAsync("***-Key", refreshedToken.AccessToken);
        await SecureStorage.SetAsync("***-RefreshToken", refreshedToken.RefreshToken);
        await SecureStorage.SetAsync("***-AccessTokenExpiration", refreshedToken.AccessTokenExpiration.ToString());
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------(AuthService) Token refresh failed:" + ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

When the code reaches `var refreshedToken = await _auth0Client.RefreshTokenAsync(storedToken);` it hangs and nothing completes afterwards. I have confirmed that `storedToken` has a valid value and is not null. Im not seeing any errors in the app or on the auth0 dashboard

Comment: did you debug? do you have an exception ? _"it hangs and nothing completes afterwards"_ What you mean ?

Comment: @Little_Dev yes I have debugged, there are no exceptions. It hits that specific line ```var refreshedToken = await _auth0Client.RefreshTokenAsync(storedToken);``` and the app just sits until vs times out the debugger (several minutes).

Comment: How are you calling this code? Are you using `await` or are you using some kind of synchronous `.Result`?

Comment: @Charlieface Im updating the post with how Im calling it

Comment: @Charlieface when I was copying over where I was calling this, I realized that I was calling it: ```bool CheckTokenStatus = _authenticationService.CheckToken().Result;``` for some reason. Changed it to ```bool CheckTokenStatus = await _authenticationService.CheckToken();```and it worked.

Comment: @Charlieface yes. I must have been in a different mental state when I wrote the CheckToken() method and when I called that method. Can you give this as the answer and I can updoot it?

Comment: I am curious: What code change did you make, that worked? (I don't see how that link helped you, since the problem there was a missing await, and the use of .Result, whereas your problem sounds like a deadlock because you are on UI thread; maybe put some code inside `await Task.Run( async () => { ... });`. FWIW: There are many previous questions with similar deadlocks, though not related to authentication.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve the issue in the link that CharlieFace provided was identical to the issue I actually had...